# How can I make image responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, responsive

am using following code to enlarge image on click...
I have tried for media in css..

http://www.frontendwebhelp.com/javascript/thumbnail-popup-to-large-image.php

But I have added one more class in # modalPopupHtml # to adjust size of large image

```
.imgsize{
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

But now I want to make that large image responsive... when I Test that code on mobile view that time it is not working properly... what should I do to make it perfect fit for mobile screen...

Comment: `width : 100%; height : auto;`

Comment: where should I add this ?

Comment: Image showing its original size... when I try this in mobile view image goes out of screen..

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 4):

Add bootstrap class (**class="img-responsive"**) to the image element

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Max-width:100%;
height:auto;
display:block
```

Answer (score 0):

by define min and max width using @media in css file

```css
    @media (max-width: px) 
{
.imgsize{  }
}
     @meida(min-width :px)
{
.imgsize{}
}
```

define px size according to your size